# How to make stamped image uneditable using iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, itext, watermark, pdfstamper, pdf-annotations

My goal is stamp an image on a *3D* PDF that behaves like a watermark (end-user **cannot** select, edit, resize, or delete the image).

I tried making an Annotation as shown below, but the image ("ClassificationBlock.png" in Resources) **can** be resized and deleted on the output PDF. Is that an inherent behavior of "PdfAnnotation" rectangles or is there a property I can define that will keep the image essentially read-only?

```
using (PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
```

.
.
.

```
                Rectangle stampRect2 = null;

                System.Drawing.Image imageBTM2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.ClassificationBlock.GetHbitmap());
                Image stampImage2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBTM2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                Rectangle location2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, stampImage2.Width, stampImage2.Height);
                PdfAnnotation pdfStamp2 = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamp.Writer, location2, null, "ImageText");
                stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                PdfAppearance app2 = stamp.GetOverContent(1).CreateAppearance(stampImage2.Width, stampImage2.Height);
                app2.AddImage(stampImage2);
                pdfStamp2.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app2);
                pdfStamp2.SetPage();
                stamp.AddAnnotation(pdfStamp2, 1);
                stampRect2 = location2;

                stamp.FormFlattening = true;

                stamp.Close();
                reader.Close();
                fs.Close();
```

I've also tried it by mimicking another user's attempt at watermark text via pdfContentBytes, but I can't get the image to even display on the PDF.

```
                    stamp.FormFlattening = false;
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageRectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
                    PdfContentByte pdfData = stamp.GetOverContent(1);
                    pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 10);
                    PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
                    graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.5F;
                    pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
                    pdfData.BeginText();

                    System.Drawing.Image imageBTM2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.TEKLAPDF_InstructionBlock.GetHbitmap());
                    iTextSharp.text.Image stampImage2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBTM2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                    float width = pageRectangle.Width;
                    float height = pageRectangle.Height;
                    stampImage2.ScaleToFit(width, height);
                    stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(width / 2 - stampImage2.Width / 2, height / 2 - stampImage2.Height / 2);
                    stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(50, 50);
                    stampImage2.Rotation = 0;

                    pdfData.AddImage(stampImage2);

                    pdfData.EndText();
```

Any ideas on how best to accomplish this? This is driving me crazy.

EDIT*****************************

These are the current avenues I've pursued. Any ideas on how to "watermark" the 3D PDF?

```
                //Stamp Image Method (works on 2D PDF and 3D PDF BUT results in EDITABLE stamp) 

                System.Drawing.Image imageBTM2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.ClassificationBlock.GetHbitmap());
                Image stampImage2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBTM2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                Rectangle stampRect2 = null;
                Rectangle location2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, stampImage2.Width, stampImage2.Height);
                PdfAnnotation pdfStamp2 = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamp.Writer, location2, null, "ImageText");
                stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                PdfAppearance app2 = stamp.GetUnderContent(1).CreateAppearance(stampImage2.Width, stampImage2.Height);
                app2.AddImage(stampImage2);
                pdfStamp2.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app2);
                pdfStamp2.SetPage();
                stamp.AddAnnotation(pdfStamp2, 1);
                stampRect2 = location2;


                //Watermark Layering Method (works only on 2D PDF)
                var layers = stamp.GetPdfLayers();

                var imgLayer = new PdfLayer("StackoverflowImage", stamp.Writer);
                PdfContentByte cb = stamp.GetUnderContent(1);
                cb.BeginLayer(imgLayer);

                stampImage2.ScalePercent(100f);
                stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(pageWidth/2, pageHeight/2);
                cb.AddImage(stampImage2);

                cb.EndLayer();


                //Jan's Watermark method (works only on 2D PDF)

                PdfContentByte over = stamp.GetOverContent(1);
                stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(pageWidth / 2, pageHeight / 2);
                PdfLayer imgLayer = new PdfLayer("StackoverflowImage", stamp.Writer);
                imgLayer.OnPanel = false;
                over.BeginLayer(imgLayer);
                over.AddImage(stampImage2);
                over.EndLayer();


                stamp.Close();
                reader.Close();
```

Comment: As your issues with @Jan's answer shows, you should also share the test PDF  you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

First off: You most likely cannot prevent selection of the image.

Second: I do itext in Java, so you'll probably end up uppercasing first character of method names...

For the remainder or your question you could try to add this image to a layer:

```
    PdfContentByte over = stamp.getOverContent(1)
    Image img = ...//code to get your image;
    img.setAbsolutePosition(x, y); //at your postion
    PdfLayer imgLayer = new PdfLayer("StackoverflowImage", stamper.getWriter());
    imgLayer.setOnPanel(false);
    over.beginLayer(imgLayer);
    over.addImage(img);
    over.endLayer();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not showing up on the PDF after running with this code form.

Comment: Where did you position it?

Comment: can you share example PDF and full stamp-image-to-pdf code you have so far?

Comment: Unfortunately it is my company's IP so I can't share it.

Comment: then create an example free from company stuff? I know that for all PDFs I've tested the above it places image on top of PDF...

Comment: But I did test it with a 3D PDF("stamp" method works but not the above "watermark" method) and a normal 2D PDF(both methods work).

The goal is the watermark method on the 3D PDF. Do you have an idea of how to do that specifically?

Comment: Jan, I've added the latest code snippets to the OP under "Edit****". Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah! 3D PDF - that might be different. I just pulled a 3D pdf for testing

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Using the "Stamp Image Method" as described above, I just needed to change the properties of the stamp itself (changing FLAGS to LOCKED and READ-ONLY). This results in a stamp that is above the 3D PDF layer AND cannot be resized, edited, or deleted. So the code is now:

```
                //Stamp Image Method 

                System.Drawing.Image imageBTM2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.ClassificationBlock.GetHbitmap());
                Image stampImage2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBTM2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                Rectangle stampRect2 = null;
                Rectangle location2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, stampImage2.Width, stampImage2.Height);
                PdfAnnotation pdfStamp2 = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamp.Writer, location2, null, "ImageText");

                pdfStamp2.Flags = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED;
                pdfStamp2.Flags = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_READONLY;

                stampImage2.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                PdfAppearance app2 = stamp.GetUnderContent(1).CreateAppearance(stampImage2.Width, stampImage2.Height);
                app2.AddImage(stampImage2);
                pdfStamp2.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app2);
                pdfStamp2.SetPage();
                stamp.AddAnnotation(pdfStamp2, 1);
                stampRect2 = location2;
```